# Include the same action in all controllers with a dynamic route in Symfony?

Tags: php, controller, symfony

I am building a service (called "dynamic_query") which I use to expose all entities to a REST API, so that if I have an entity diagram like this one:

**[continent--(has many)-->country--(has many)-->city]**

I can get countries (JSON list) that are in let say Africa through the URL:

**http://www.example.com/country/api/?continent=africa**

And even for indirectly related entities, I still can get results:
for example, to list all cities which belong to countries situated in Europe:

**http://www.example.com/city/api/?continent=europe**

The service is ready and tested, and here is how I use it within the City Controller taken as an example:

```
/**
* City controller.
*
* @Route("city")
*/
class CityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/api/", name="city_api",options = { "expose" = true })
     * @Method("GET")
     * 
     */
     public function apiAction(Request $request)
     {

        $conditions=$request->query->all();

        $results=$this->get("app.dynamic_query")
                      ->narrow("city",$conditions);

        return new Response($results);
      }
}
```

What I'm looking for right now is to find a way to "duplicate" this *apiAction()* ** with its route** and make it available in every entity in my bundle, so that whenever I access:

**http://www.example.com/entity/api/?arg_1=val_1&arg_2=val_2&arg_n=val_n**

I got exactly the same logic shown above in the apiAction(), except the $entity_name and the route name/uri should change dynamically to fit the api query

Comment: It sounds like you want some sort of a global controller not in the '/city' route prefix. In this controller you could configure a route with variable parts, like `/{entity}/api` for method GET. Then have a switch statement or something to get the name of the entity based on the route slug and change the FROM part of the dql to use this entity name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to mickadoo comment's, in my case this is what i use to do it:

routing.yml:

```
list_entities:
    path:     /admin/list/{class}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Admin:listEntities, page : 1 }
    requirements:
        methods:  GET
        class: region|department|city|user|type|category|offer|report|comment
        page: \d+
```

AdminController:

```
class AdminController extends Controller{

    private $entities_bundle = array('region' => 'LocalizationBundle',
                                    'department' => 'LocalizationBundle',
                                    'city' => 'LocalizationBundle',
                                    'user' => 'MainBundle',
                                    'type' => 'MainBundle',
                                    'category' => 'MainBundle',
                                    'offer' => 'MainBundle',
                                    'report' => 'MainBundle',
                                    'comment' => 'MainBundle');

    private $entity_entities = array('region' => 'regions',
                                    'department' => 'departments',
                                    'city' => 'cities',
                                    'user' => 'users',
                                    'type' => 'types',
                                    'category' => 'categories',
                                    'offer' => 'offers',
                                    'report' => 'reports',
                                    'comment' => 'comments');

...

public function listEntitiesAction($class, $page = 1){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository($this->entities_bundle[$class].":".ucfirst($class))->findPaginateListForAdmin(30, $page);

    //Your logic

    return $this->render('AdminBundle:Admin:list_'.$this->entity_entities[$class].'.html.twig', array('parameters' => $parameters));


}
```

It's not for REST API but i think you can adapt this code easily for your case. But you need mutual controller.